# Undefined exported symbol with emscripten docker image

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

What am I missing?

```
[ad@tank prolly]$ cat wam.c
int wam() { return 2; }

[ad@tank prolly]$ /usr/bin/docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src emscripten/emsdk emcc --no-entry -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=wam wam.c
emcc: error: undefined exported symbol: "wam" [-Wundefined] [-Werror]
```

I'm doing the EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS bit because Javascript couldn't find the symbol either. The browser console said:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: instance.exports.wam is not a function
```

after:

```
  <script type="module">
    async function init() {
      const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming( fetch("./wam.wasm"));
      instance.exports.wam();
    }
    init();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. You have to put `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_wam` (with the underscore) otherwise it doesn't export it. Hopefully there's also a `--export-all` but it isn't called that. Then `instance.exports.wam();` will work;